# Count in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following data:

```
Comp  ID    Name  Type
-----------------------
AAA   D2222 Jon   BR11
AAA   D2222 Jon   BR12
AAA   D2865 Toe   BR11
BBB   D4151 Sue   BR11
BBB   D4151 Sue   BR12
BBB   D4151 Sue   BR13
CCC   D6080 Pete  BR14
CCC   D6723 Tom   BR13
```

I want to write my SQL statement and display like table below

```
Comp BR11  BR12  BR13  BR14
---------------------------
AAA   2     1       
BBB   1     1      1    
CCC                1    1
```

But I only know to select for one Type, how can I do it for many Types ?

```
select 
    Comp, count(Type) as BR11
from 
    CCDL 
where 
    Type = 'BR11'
group by 
    Comp
```

Thanks much !

Comment: hint :  use of pivot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use selective aggregates for this:

```
SELECT Comp
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'BR11' THEN 1 END) br11
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'BR12' THEN 1 END) br12
     ,  ...
  FROM CCDL
 GROUP BY Comp
```

More about this: http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

It's basically also a pivot technique: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic pivot is the best approach:

```
create  table test (Comp varchar(3), ID varchar(10), Name varchar(10), Type varchar(10))

insert into test values ('AAA','D2222','Jon','BR11');            
insert into test values ('AAA','D2222','Jon','BR12');            
insert into test values ('AAA','D2865','Toe','BR11');            
insert into test values ('BBB','D4151','Sue','BR11');            
insert into test values ('BBB','D4151','Sue','BR12');            
insert into test values ('BBB','D4151','Sue','BR13');            
insert into test values ('CCC','D6080','Pete','BR14');           
insert into test values ('CCC','D6723','Tom','BR13');            



DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Type) 
            FROM test c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Comp, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Comp
                    , ID
                    , Type
                from test
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 count(ID)
                for Type in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

The result is

```
Comp    BR11    BR12    BR13    BR14
AAA       2       1       0      0
BBB       1       1       1      0 
CCC       0       0       1      1
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following code

```
declare @tab table (Comp varchar(50),Id varchar(50),Name varchar(50),Type varchar(50))
insert into @tab 
Select 'AAA','D2222','Jon','BR11' Union ALL
Select 'AAA','D2222','Jon','BR12' Union ALL
Select 'AAA','D2865','Toe','BR11' Union ALL
Select 'BBB','D4151','Sue','BR11' Union ALL
Select 'BBB','D4151','Sue','BR12' Union ALL
Select 'BBB','D4151','Sue','BR13' Union ALL
Select 'CCC','D6080','Pete','BR14'Union ALL
Select 'CCC','D6723','Tom','BR13'
Select *  from 
(Select  type,comp,count(*) cnt from @tab
group by type,Comp

)d
PIVOT
(Sum(Cnt) FOR Type in ([BR11],[BR12],[BR13],[BR14]))p
```

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS** : Use `CASE` with `SUM` as below:

```
SELECT Comp, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'BR11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) br11,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'BR12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) br12,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'BR13' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) br13,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'BR14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) br14
FROM CCDL
GROUP BY Comp
```

Answer (score 1):

**What you can do**

[image: here]

```
SELECT Comp, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'BR11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) br11,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'BR12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) br12,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'BR13' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) br13,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'BR14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) br14
FROM CCDL
GROUP BY Comp
```